# Aliases in scripts are not set globally

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I know this sound really wierd but this is exactly what happens. I have my `.profile` and `.bashrc` file set up in a way that the `.bash_aliases` file gets executed (checked it with a echo). I do not get any errors and the aliases have worked an another machine.

I use the following command to see what aliases are registered.

```
echo $(alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sort -u)
```

I put this in the `.bash_aliases` file and it showed my aliases. Then I put it in the `.bashrc` file right after the call of the `.bash_aliases` file. The amazing thing is that the aliases, that have just bein created **and** printed, have vanished! They do no longer exist!

To show it better I'm going to give you the output when I log in and the content of the files.

Output:

```
Aliases before .bashrc

Aliases before .bash_aliases
alias alert alias dir alias egrep alias fgrep alias grep alias l alias la alias ll alias ls alias vdir
Aliases before executing .bash_aliases

Aliases after executing .bash_aliases
alias duh alias l. alias server alias sh alias testserver
Aliases after .bash_aliases
alias alert alias dir alias egrep alias fgrep alias grep alias l alias la alias ll alias ls alias vdir
Aliases after .bashrc
```

`.profile`:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

echo Aliases before .bashrc
echo $(alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sort -u)

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
         bash "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

echo Aliases after .bashrc
echo $(alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sort -u)

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

`.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

echo Aliases before .bash_aliases
echo $(alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sort -u)

if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ]; then
    bash "$HOME/.bash_aliases"
fi

echo Aliases after .bash_aliases
echo $(alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sort -u)

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
    if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
        bash /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion    
    elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
        bash /etc/bash_completion
    fi
fi
```

`.bash_aliases`:

```
echo Aliases before executing .bash_aliases
echo $(alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sort -u)

alias server="bash ~/start.sh"
alias testserver="bash ~/test/start.sh"
alias sh="bash"

## Show hidden files ##
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'

memory() {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    parameter=("-sc" *)
  else
    parameter=("$@")
  fi

  du -Lb "${parameter[@]}" | awk '
    function hr(bytes) {
      hum[1099511627776]="TiB";
      hum[1073741824]="GiB";
      hum[1048576]="MiB";
      hum[1024]="kiB";
      for (x = 1099511627776; x >= 1024; x /= 1024) {
        if (bytes >= x) {
          return sprintf("%8.3f %s", bytes/x, hum[x]);
        }
      }
      return sprintf("%4d     B", bytes);
    }

    {
      print hr($1) "\t" $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
    }
  ';
}

alias duh="memory"

echo Aliases after executing .bash_aliases
echo $(alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sort -u)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your `.bashrc` in a subshell.  Which exits.

Bad:

```
bash ~/.bashrc
```

You need to source the file.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. These are these little things that drive you crazy!